# Transaction in feathersjs using Objection ORM

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, objection.js, feathers-service

[feathers-objection](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-objection) - A service adapter for [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js) - A minimal SQL ORM built on top of Knex.

*Transactions* are atomic and isolated units of work in relational databases.

We want to create and use transaction in feathersjs application generated using the Feathers CLI.

**But**

We were not able to figure out how to create a transaction object and pass it to series of service calls using the transaction params operator and how to use await *transaction.trx.commit()* and await *transaction.trx.rollback()*.

Help is required for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve transaction in feathersjs using objection ORM.

Findings are as follows.

*transaction-hooks*

```
const {transaction} = require('objection');
// Use this hook to manipulate incoming or outgoing data.
// For more information on hooks see: http://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const start = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const { service } = context;
    const Model = service.Model;
    const trx = await transaction.start(Model); // use Model if you have installed a knex instance globally using the Model.knex() method, otherwise use Model.knex()
    context.params.transaction = { trx };
    return context;
  };
};
const commit = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const { transaction } = context.params;
    await transaction.trx.commit();
    return context;
  };
};
const rollback = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const { transaction } = context.params;
    await transaction.trx.rollback();
  };
};
module.exports = {
  _transaction: {
    start,
    commit,
    rollback
  }
};
```

Then in your *service.hooks* use the following:

```
const {_transaction} = require('../../hooks/transaction-hooks');
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [_transaction.start(),createRideData],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [updateRideRequestStatus, _transaction.commit()],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [_transaction.rollback()],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

One can also start transaction with the knex instance:

```
const start = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const { service, app } = context;
    const knex = app.get('knex');
    const trx = await transaction.start(knex);
    context.params = {
      ...context.params,
      transaction: {
        trx
      }
    }
    return context;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `knex.transcationProvider()` example from https://knexjs.org/#Transactions

However there might be a bug in documentation in the part where `await trx.commit()` and `await trx.rollback()` are called.

Safer way would be to just call either of those without `await` and `await trx.executionPromise` to get transaction result / error if it was rolled back.

Transaction documentation in knex is currently quite messy.